# worksheet macro for multiple cells

Tags: excel, vba

i have a little code for a change in a worksheet . if in a range something changes than in a other cell the date will appear .

this is for keeping track of the last changes.

this works for one table in my worksheet but i have multiple tables for which i want to do the same .
see below the code i have for one table ..

so how can i extend this for multiple tables in the same sheet ?

looking forward to your reply

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

 Dim xRg As Range
  On Error Resume Next
     Set xRg = Intersect(Target, Range("DATASENDUR"))
    If xRg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    Range("B22").Value = Now()
 End Sub
```

Comment: So you want to apply the same macro to more than one `Target`?

Comment: Remove `On Error Resume Next` this line hides all errors but they still occur you just cannot see them. This makes you blind for any errors. [VBA Error Handling – A Complete Guide](https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-error-handling)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that you must disable events `Application.EnableEvents = False` before writing into cells in the `Worksheet_Change` event otherwise it will trigger the event again and again …

You can check a second range as shown below.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim xRg As Range

    'check changes in first range
    Set xRg = Intersect(Target, Me.Range("DATASENDUR"))
    If Not xRg Is Nothing Then 
        Application.EnableEvents = False 'prevent to trigger another Worksheet_Change event!
        Me.Range("B22").Value = Now()
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If

    'check changes in OTHER range
    Set xRg = Intersect(Target, Me.Range("OTHERRANGE"))
    If Not xRg Is Nothing Then 
        Application.EnableEvents = False 'prevent to trigger another Worksheet_Change event!
        Me.Range("B25").Value = Now()
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Many thanks for the feedback makes sens i will try it out .many thanks